# Rails using checkbox for adding tags to posts ( many to many )

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Post model and Tag model with many to many relationships.

## Post Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

## Tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

I also have a join table for `posts_tags` :

```
class JoinPostsAndTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts_tags do |t|
        t.integer :tag_id
        t.integer :post_id

        t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I need to provide multiple selection for selecting tags for a post.

**Below is the post `form.html.erb`**

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post     from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
<%= f.label :Name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :Name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :Email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Message %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :Message %>
  </div>

  <% @tags= Tag.all %>
  <% if @tags %>
  <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
    <div>
        <%= check_box_tag "post[tag_ids][]", tag.id, @post.tags.include?(tag) %>
        <%= tag.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>


  <br><br>

  <%= link_to 'Create Tag', tags_path %>
     <br><br>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It is not adding the selected tags to the post. I need to add the selected tags to the post. How can I do it.
                                                                                                          But, in **rails console** if I use `post= Post.first` `tag= Tag.first`  `post.tags<<tag` it adds the `tag` to the `post`.
I don't have any special code in `post controller` to handle this. Please help me.

Comment: What do your post params look like when they come in to the server? Also, what are you doing with `@topic`?

Comment: I removed the @topic. Please look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `{tag_ids:[]}` to your `params` `permit` arguments in your `PostsController`, like so:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, :message, {tag_ids:[]})
end
```